# In R Program, want to fill a matrix from vector values across rows at a a specific column with specific value

Tags: r, matrix, apply, fill

In R Program, I have a matrix containing 0 and 1's. See Below

```
0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1
```

I want to fill the matrix byrow from values listed (c("J" "J" "A" "A" "A" "A" "... continue "A" until end of matrix") but begin at the first 1 in each row. See below:

```
0 J J A A A
0 J J A A A 
0 0 0 J J A
0 J J A A A
0 0 0 0 0 J
```

As of now, I have created a values list and a function to determine where the first 1 is. I'm lost on how to apply this to get the matrix I want.

`pattern<- c("A","A","A","A","A")`
`pattern <- c("J","J",  rep(pattern, length.out = ncol(Matrix)-2))`
`indices<- apply(Matrix, 1, function(row) min(which(row == 1)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few vectorized options:

```
m <- max.col(cbind(mat, 1L), "f")
m <- rbind(m - 1L, pmin(2L, ncol(mat) - m + 1L), pmax(0L, ncol(mat) - m - 1L))
matrix(c("0", "J", "A")[rep.int(row(m), m)], nrow(mat), ncol(mat), 1)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [2,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"  "J"  "A" 
#> [4,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"
```

Or

```
m <- max.col(cbind(mat, 1L), "f")
array(c("0", "J", "A")[(col(mat) >= m) + (col(mat) > m + 1L) + 1L], dim(mat))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [2,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"  "J"  "A" 
#> [4,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"
```

Or

```
matrix(
  rep.int(c("0", "J", "A"), c(ncol(mat), 2L, ncol(mat) - 2L))[
    sequence(rep(ncol(mat), nrow(mat)), ncol(mat) - max.col(cbind(mat, 1L), "f") + 2L)
  ], nrow(mat), ncol(mat), 1
)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [2,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"  "J"  "A" 
#> [4,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
#> [5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"
```

---

Benchmarking shows the advantage of using a vectorized approach. Define various approaches as functions:

```
f1 <- function(mat) {
  m <- max.col(cbind(mat, 1L), "f")
  m <- rbind(m - 1L, pmin(2L, ncol(mat) - m + 1L), pmax(0L, ncol(mat) - m - 1L))
  matrix(c("0", "J", "A")[rep.int(row(m), m)], nrow(mat), ncol(mat), 1)
}

f2 <- function(mat) {
  m <- max.col(cbind(mat, 1L), "f")
  array(c("0", "J", "A")[(col(mat) >= m) + (col(mat) > m + 1L) + 1L], dim(mat))
}

f3 <- function(mat) {
  d <- dim(mat)
  matrix(
    rep.int(c("0", "J", "A"), c(d[2], 2L, d[2] - 2L))[
      sequence(rep(d[2], d[1]), d[2] - max.col(cbind(mat, 1L), "f") + 2L)
    ], d[1], d[2], 1
  )
}

Andre <- function(mat) {
  # from Andre Wildberg
  t(apply(mat, 1, function(x){
    res <- which(x == 1)[1] - 1
    res <- replace(res, is.na(res), length(x))
    c(x[0:res], 
      rep("J", min(c(2, (length(x) - res)))),
      rep("A", max(c(0, (length(x) - res) - 2))))}))
}
```

Benchmark on a large-ish matrix.

```
mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 1e5, 1, c(0.75, 0.25)), 1e4)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  f1 = f1(mat),
  f2 = f2(mat),
  f3 = f3(mat),
  Andre = Andre(mat),
  check = "equal"
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>   expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
#>     f1  1.391700  1.894001  2.127106  1.967701  2.097001   7.966101   100
#>     f2  1.616000  2.240750  2.691387  2.361451  2.590051   7.142301   100
#>     f3  1.118401  1.570600  1.745991  1.619800  1.739251   5.924802   100
#>  Andre 68.022601 70.696101 73.181934 72.200000 73.931750 117.784401   100
```

Comment: Your second answer worked with my data! Thank you so much!. New to R Program, what exactly does 1L do?

Comment: I would have expected all three to work, with the third probably being the fastest. `1L` refers to the integer representation of 1, rather than the double-precision float representation. It uses roughly half the memory, which would only become important if the matrix were very large.

Answer (score 0):

Get the first part of zeros, then fill the "J"s, finally add the "A"s.

```
t(apply(mat, 1, function(x){
  res <- which(x == 1)[1] - 1
  res <- replace(res, is.na(res), length(x))
  c(x[0:res], 
    rep("J", min(c(2, (length(x) - res)))),
    rep("A", max(c(0, (length(x) - res) - 2))))}))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
[2,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
[3,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
[4,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"  "J"  "A" 
[5,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
[6,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "J" 
[7,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"
```

##### Data

```
mat <- structure(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0), dim = 7:6)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I ran your code for your matrix and it work. I tried running it for my matrix [1:669, 1:6]. Unfortunately something was off and it created a list of 1 row with 669 columns containing the values c(ColumnName = "1", "J", "J", "A", "A", "A", "A"). I'm not sure what went wrong, would it be that I have names for my columns as opposed to V1- V6? Any thoughts would be helpful! Thank you again.

Comment: @ariggs154 Hmm, there might have been a problem when there were no 1s in a row. Should work now with your data.

Comment: So all of my points should have at least 1 "1" in them. The code wasn't liking the beginning. If I plug in my matrix as "x' and ran the following code "2:which(x ==1)[1]-1 ; I got 1 0. Your code with your matrix spit 1 2 3 4 5 (which I assumed as column numbers minus 1). It's weird, I feel like your code should work as a solution but it doesn't want to.

Comment: @ariggs154 Ok, no worries, thanks for trying. Another test can be to run it with a smaller subset, e.g. `mat[1:10,1:6]`. Eventually, try the other solutions and pick what works best for you!

Answer (score 0):

```
vec = c("J", "J", rep("A", ncol(m) - 2))
m |> 
  apply(MARGIN = 1, \(x) {
    x = cumsum(x) > 0
    y = rep("0", length(x))
    y[x] = vec[seq_len(sum(x))]
    y
  }) |>
  t()
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
# [2,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
# [3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"  "J"  "A" 
# [4,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
# [5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
m = read.table(text = '0 1 0 1 0 0 
0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1') |> as.matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

feels easier to just do:

```
n <- ncol(m)
vec <- c("J", "J", rep("A", n - 2))
t(apply(mat, 1, \(x)c(numeric(which(x>0)[1]-1), vec)[seq(n)]))

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
[2,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
[3,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"  "J"  "A" 
[4,] "0"  "J"  "J"  "A"  "A"  "A" 
[5,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "J"
```